# Spyder version 4.2.3 lagging on Mac, OS Big Sur

Tags: python, spyder, macos-big-sur

When I type in Spyder (Mac OS Big Sur), I am faced with some significant lag.

I have seen stack overflow posts that indicate that this problem was solved in a recent version of  Spyder. However, when I updated Spyder to 4.2.3, my lag issue has persisted.

All typing takes 1-3 seconds to register and show up in both the console and any scripts I am writing. I have tried restarting repeatedly, and spyder has also shut down on its own. I am sure that is somehow related.

I have also tried following the steps in this link, but they did not work: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#troubleshooting-macos-bigsur

Comment: With Spyder 5 and Big Sur 11.4 this problem persists. I know that the solution is to download the .dmg, but a good solution is that the Spyder that comes with Anaconda Navigator works without lagging.

Comment: I downloaded anaconda just a few weeks ago with default Spyder 5.0.0 (update to only 5.0.3 was possible with conda while 5.0.5 was avaialble on github https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases) and Python 3.8.8. It was laggy even after trying the recommended fix of `export QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER=1`(https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#troubleshooting-macos-bigsur). I downloaded the lates Spyder from github directly and it _solved_ the problem (I still consider it a workaround, though).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem (Macbook Pro 13" 2017 Big Sur 11.2.3), I even did a factory reset on my macbook. Once I had my computer fresh and clean, I downloaded Anaconda, launched Spyder 4.1.5 (the default one when you open Anaconda Navigator the first time) and it was laggy as usual. So I closed everything, opened the terminal and followed the FAQ steps :

```
conda create -n spyder-dev python=3
conda activate spyder-dev
conda install -c conda-forge spyder
```

Then

```
conda activate spyder-dev
export QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER=1
spyder
```

Every forum i read said that the "QT_MAC_WANTS_LAYER=1" part solved the problem, so i had high expectations. But the lagging persisted (Spyder 4.2.5 , Python 3.9)

The final solution was to download the .dmg file app spyder has now, and it seems to be functioning without lag and without typing latency. Also it launches very quickly.

It's the only solution i know, hope it helps!

Comment: Still seems to be the only way to overcome the problem. Works like a charm, though, so thanks!